# Log Out Controller crashes instead of allowing user to log out

Tags: ios, objective-c, controller, logout

I have a self-made *"log out controller"* for my app, and I would appreciate your help on a problem.

My *"log out controller"* is included my app, accessed by a simple side swipe from another controller; however, I've placed the *"log out"* button in a simple `UITableViewController`.

My problem occurs when I hit the *"log out"* button, the app crashes, and I'm unsure of quite how to parse the data so that the user is successfully logged out once they hit the button. If anybody could tell me where I'm going wrong it would be lifesaving!

```
- (IBAction)logOutAction:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"yes");

    PDKeychainBindings *bindings = [PDKeychainBindings sharedKeychainBindings];
    [bindings setObject:@"no" forKey:@"loggedIn"];
    [bindings setObject:@"" forKey:@"userID"];

    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)window.rootViewController;
    UIViewController *login = [nav.viewControllers  objectAtIndex:0];
    UINavigationController *slider = (UINavigationController*)login.presentedViewController;

    self.logOutButton.enabled = NO;
    [self.logOutButton setAlpha:0.8];

    [self performSelector:@selector(logOutAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [login dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ 

    }];
}


- (IBAction)close:(id)sender {

    //UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    //DYNavigationController *nav = (DYNavigationController*)window.rootViewController;
    //UIViewController *login = [nav.viewControllerStack objectAtIndex:0];
    // CustomNavController *slider = (CustomNavController*)login.presentedViewController;
    //[self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    //[login dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{    
    // }];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You need to give details of the exception! Show the exception name, description and stack trace.

Comment: Why you are performing selector on the IBOutlet

Comment: where it crashes and what is exception about exactly

Comment: please provide crash log..

Comment: You are calling `logOutAction:` method recursively by using `[self performSelector:@selector(logOutAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];` inside `logOutAction:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't given exception details, but it looks like you are calling the instance after is has been deallocated.

In the `logOutAction:` method you are setting up a future call using `[self performSelector:@selector(logOutAction:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];`. Then you are dismissing the view. So when `logOutAction:` is called in `0.1` seconds the instance wont exist and you will crash.

It makes no sense to use `performSelector` here - remove it.